# What are the best packages for HMM sequence analysis?

Tags: r, python, hidden-markov-model, sequence-analysis

I have a sequence of events and I want to learn discrete probabilities of transitions between them and to predict next item in a sequence.

Can you point me on good papers and Python or R package for this topic?

Answer (score 1):

You could look at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/45810/appropriate-r-package-function-for-applying-hmm-to-categorical-sequence-data?rq=1 for some hints to get you started. Although it is old the advice should help you find R packages.